# build XML button in android studio

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, kotlin, button

how can I build a FAB button like this one to expand a view in android studio with XML?

[this is the button I need to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB2TO.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you need to rounded button, so you can use a FAB button, like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_options"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabCustomSize="40dp"
        />
```

Then you can place it where you need.